# Using QCMDEXC to call QEZSNDMG via DB2 stored procedure

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Working on a side project where I use a set of views to identify contention of records within an iSeries set of physical files.

What I would like to do once identified is pull the user profile locking the record, and then send a break message to their terminal as an informational break message.

What I have found is the QEZSNDMG API. Simple enough to use interactively, but I'm trying to put together a command that would be used in conjunction with QCMDEXC API to issue the call to QEZSNDMG and alert the user that they are locking a record.

Reviewing the [IBM documentation of the QEZSNDMG API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_61/apis/QEZSNDMG.htm), I see that there are two sets of option parameters, but nothing as required (which seems odd to me, but another topic for another day). But I continue to receive the error "Parameters passed on CALL do not match those required."

Here are some examples that I have tried from the command line so far:

1. CALL PGM(QEZSNDMG) PARM('*INFO' '*BREAK' 'TEST' '4' 'DOUGLAS' '1' '1' '-4')
2. CALL PGM(QEZSNDMG) PARM('*INFO' '*BREAK' 'TEST' '4' 'DOUGLAS')
3. CALL PGM(QEZSNDMG) PARM('*INFO' '*BREAK' 'TEST' '4' 'DOUGLAS' '1')

Note: I would like to avoid using a CL or RPG program if possible but understand it may come to that using one of many examples I found before posting. Just want to exhaust this option before going down that road.

**Update**
While logged in, I used WRKMSGQ to see the message queues assigned to my station. There were two: QSYS/DOUGLAS and QUSRSYS/DOUGLAS. I then issued SNDBRKMSG with no affect on my workstation (IE, the message didn't break my session):

- SNDBRKMSG MSG(TESTING) TOMSGQ(QSYS/DOUGLAS)
- SNDBRKMSG MSG(TESTING) TOMSGQ(QUSRSYS/DOUGLAS)

I realized if I provide the workstation session name in the TOMSG parameter it worked:

- SNDBRKMSG MSG(TESTING) TOMSGQ(*LIBL/QPADEV0003)

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use SNDMSG or SNDBRKMSG for this purpose?

Comment: @Player1st : Please correct me if I'm wrong, but SNDMSG does not have a break function, I would need the user to be interrupted. For SNDBRKMSG, I do not believe you can specify a specific user, it sends to all users active or otherwise.

Comment: I think you can supply a message queue name and library that can narrow it down to one user.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/sndbrkmsg.htm\

Comment: @Mike : WRKMSGQ shows two message queues on my session. When I supply both, I get a message saying the message didn't break. I'll update my question with what I did and the results.

Comment: @Mike : So I found I could supply the workstation ID to the SNDBRKMSG command. I just need to ensure I have the workstation ID available in my checks to QSYS2/RCD_LCK and I should be good to go.

Comment: As some additional info when you call QEZSNDMG using the CALL command, it doesn't actually have any parameters. It's a program using the API that is meant to be used interactively. Ultimately you have the QEZSNDMG API which you would have to write your own program to use or you have the QEZSNDMG program you use interactively to send a message.

Comment: Good you did it on your own.  Those API are really tricky to call from the command line and it might not work at all but you should learn how to pass hex numbers.   for example to pass 4 binary 0 is something like CALL PGM(QEZSNDMG) PARM('*INFO' '*BREAK' 'TEST' x'04'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SNDBRKMSG was what I was looking for.

Some nudging in the right direction lead me to realize that the workstation session ID is located within QSYS2.RCD_LOCK in field JOB_NAME (job number/username/workstation).

Extracting the workstation ID allowed me to create a correctly formatted SNDBRKMSG command to QCMDEXC and alert the user that they are locking a record needed by another process.